# fb:login-button Problems

Tags: facebook-graph-api, button, authentication, facebook

I'm having troubles with the login tag "fb:login-button". If I login works fine, but if I logout it doesn't really logout I have to refresh the page to be completly logged out

Comment: what language/technology are you using? example code? Can you not use a javascript redirect or another redirect to refresh the page? Also is that not deprecated and could you not use http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use, maybe it can help you. Take a look at the events I subscribe to. After login/logout, it refreshes the page automatically:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId: '<?php echo $facebook->getAppID() ?>', 
      cookie: true, 
      xfbml: true,
      oauth: true
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
        window.location.reload();
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
        window.location.reload();
    });
  };
```